# XSLT output gives extra <Columns> node

Tags: xml, xslt

My final XML should be of following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Rowsets>
    <Rowset>
        <Columns></Columns>
        <Row></Row>
        <Row></Row>
        <Row></Row>     
    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

I am currently merging two XMLs and it gives me following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Rowsets>
    <Rowset>
        <Columns>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Material" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Material"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="DS_MATERIAL" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="DS_MATERIAL"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Press" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Press"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Mold" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Mold"/>
        </Columns>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>111</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>14</Press>
            <Mold>3864F</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>111</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>25</Press>
            <Mold>4306K-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>111</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>25</Press>
            <Mold>4306K-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>111</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>Summary</Press>
            <Mold>---</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953-1</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>111</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>23</Press>
            <Mold>4305P-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953-1</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>111</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>23</Press>
            <Mold>4305P-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953-1</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>---</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>Summary</Press>
            <Mold>---</Mold>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
    <Rowset>
        <Columns>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Material" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Material"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="DS_MATERIAL" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="DS_MATERIAL"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Press" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Press"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Mold" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Mold"/>
        </Columns>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>222</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>14</Press>
            <Mold>3864F</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>222</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>25</Press>
            <Mold>4306K-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>222</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>25</Press>
            <Mold>4306K-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>222</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>Summary</Press>
            <Mold>---</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953-1</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>222</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>23</Press>
            <Mold>4305P-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953-1</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>222</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>23</Press>
            <Mold>4305P-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953-1</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>222</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>Summary</Press>
            <Mold>---</Mold>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

Now as I need only one `<Rowset>` and all the `<Row>` inside that `<Rowset>`, I am applying following XSLT to above XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" exclude-result-prefixes="java" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output media-type="text/xml" method="xml"/>
    <!-- Merges multiple rowsets -->
    <xsl:param name="SD"/>
    <xsl:param name="ED"/>
    <xsl:param name="RowCount"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Rowsets>
          <Rowset>
            <xsl:copy-of select="/Rowsets/Rowset/Columns"/>
              <xsl:for-each select="Rowsets/Rowset">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Row"/>
              </xsl:for-each>
           </Rowset>
        </Rowsets>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This creates all of the `<Row>` inside one `<Rowset>` but it creates two `<Columns>` nodes. I need only one `<Columns>` node.

Resultant XML of above XSLT is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Rowsets>
    <Rowset>
        <Columns>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Material" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Material"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="DS_MATERIAL" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="DS_MATERIAL"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Press" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Press"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Mold" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Mold"/>
        </Columns>
        <Columns>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Material" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Material"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="DS_MATERIAL" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="DS_MATERIAL"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Press" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Press"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Mold" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Mold"/>
        </Columns>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>111</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>14</Press>
            <Mold>3864F</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>111</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>25</Press>
            <Mold>4306K-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>111</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>25</Press>
            <Mold>4306K-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>111</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>Summary</Press>
            <Mold>---</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953-1</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>111</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>23</Press>
            <Mold>4305P-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953-1</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>111</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>23</Press>
            <Mold>4305P-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953-1</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>---</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>Summary</Press>
            <Mold>---</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>222</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>14</Press>
            <Mold>3864F</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>222</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>25</Press>
            <Mold>4306K-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>222</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>25</Press>
            <Mold>4306K-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>222</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>Summary</Press>
            <Mold>---</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953-1</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>222</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>23</Press>
            <Mold>4305P-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953-1</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>222</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>23</Press>
            <Mold>4305P-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953-1</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>222</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>Summary</Press>
            <Mold>---</Mold>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

What modification is required for my XSLT to remove this extra `<Columns>` node?

The XML which I need is as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Rowsets>
    <Rowset>
        <Columns>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Material" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Material"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="DS_MATERIAL" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="DS_MATERIAL"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Press" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Press"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Mold" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Mold"/>
        </Columns>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>111</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>14</Press>
            <Mold>3864F</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>111</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>25</Press>
            <Mold>4306K-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>111</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>25</Press>
            <Mold>4306K-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>111</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>Summary</Press>
            <Mold>---</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953-1</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>111</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>23</Press>
            <Mold>4305P-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953-1</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>111</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>23</Press>
            <Mold>4305P-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953-1</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>---</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>Summary</Press>
            <Mold>---</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>222</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>14</Press>
            <Mold>3864F</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>222</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>25</Press>
            <Mold>4306K-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>222</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>25</Press>
            <Mold>4306K-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>222</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>Summary</Press>
            <Mold>---</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953-1</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>222</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>23</Press>
            <Mold>4305P-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953-1</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>222</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>23</Press>
            <Mold>4305P-1</Mold>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Material>300-6953-1</Material>
            <DS_MATERIAL>222</DS_MATERIAL>
            <Press>Summary</Press>
            <Mold>---</Mold>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

Please help.

Comment: Could you post the exact and full output expected as the result of transforming the shown input example?

Comment: Added the XML which I need. It is just that I dont need duplicate <Columns></Columns> in the resultant XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Rowsets">
    <Rowsets>
        <Rowset>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Rowset[1]/Columns"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Rowset/Row"/>
        </Rowset>
    </Rowsets>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

> I am currently merging two XMLs and it gives me follwoing XML:

You could probably fix this in your merging XSLT and save yourself the need for an additional transformation.